# what the difference between @Buffer.Memory^ and Buffer.Memory?

Tags: delphi

With buffer a `TMemoryStream` (so with Buffer.Memory = pointer), what is the difference between `@Buffer.Memory^` and `Buffer.Memory` ?

Comment: When in doubt, ask the compiler: `Type TBuffer = record  buf: Pointer; end; var b : TBuffer; begin b.buf := Pointer(42);  WriteLn(@b.buf^ = b.buf); ReadLn;end.`

Comment: @P^ is in fact the same as @(P^) (get the address of the value to which a pointer points, which is the same as the address in the pointer). That only works if P is a pointer.

Comment: @Rudy I think you mean to compare (@P)^ and @(P^) where the explicit parens are used in case it is not clear what the precedence of these unary operators is. Which would not be surprising since it isn't documented for some unfathomable reason. Presumably @P^ is one of the two above expressions, but it doesn't matter which because @ and ^ are inverse operations.

Comment: Is this where the people over at the C-world would go berserk on _rvalue_ en _lvalue_ stuff?

Comment: @David: IIRC, `@(P^)` works, but `(@P)^` doesn't, if `P` is a pointer. I could be wrong though. Actually, I'd expect `(@I)^ := 4;`to compile too (if `I` is an Integer variable here), but it doesn't. `PI := @I; PI^ := 4` does compile though (`PI` is a `PInteger`);. `(@I)` is an expression of type `PInteger`, after all, so `(@I)^ := 4;` should compile, IMO.

Comment: `(@P)^` is meaningful is `$TYPEDADDRESS` in `ON`, as it should be

Comment: I guess the typed address off behaviour telling us that the compiler parses @P^ as @(P^)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between these two expressions.

Your question can be simplified to asking the difference between these expressions

```
P
@P^
```

where `P` has type `Pointer`. It should hopefully be clear that these two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: thanks david, i ask because in source code of delphi (in SoapHttpTrans.pas) they do @Buffer.Memory^ and was curious why

Comment: Code likely written by underpaid intern, and Emba don't have a proper code review process

Comment: @david: that code uses `Buffer.Memory^` quite often, so I can imagine why someone would try to get the address of that not by removing the `^` but by adding a `@` in front. It could happen to me too, and I am not an underpaid intern. <g>